# Editing workspace source associated with jar file in same workspace

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I have a project A in eclipse whose code is compiled into a jar and used by a separate project B.
I have associated the jar to the workspace project A code. 
When I run project B I get stack trace on the console which references the jar.
When clicking on the references the correct file opens up from project A but as read only, I want to edit this file and fix my code. 
What I end up doing is open the file manually using search typing the name or navigating to it in the package explorer and then edit it.
I mean file is there in the project in my workspace, why is it not editable?
Is there any way around it?

Comment: More details project A is a regular Java project and B is a plugin project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open a Java file of project A with the *Java Editor* (editable) instead of with the *Java Class Viewer* (read-only) when you are in your project B, you have to do the following:

1. **Right-click project B** and choose ***Properties***
2. In ***Java Build Path***, tab ***Projects*** click ***Add...***
3. **Select project A** and click ***OK***
4. In ***Java Build Path***, tab ***Order and Export* move project A to the top** by selecting project A and clicking *UP* several times
5. Click ***Apply and Close*** to close properties dialog of project B

I would **recommend convert project A to a plug-in project**. A plug-in JAR can be used in both, a plain Java and an OSGi application. The code would be more modular and changes in project A would not require a JAR file to be updated in project B.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working, I removed my jar and converted project A to plugin project. Simpler build. By the way the conversion was a required step not optional for the solution to work.